# DNS Records: One IP for Primary Domain and One IP for Multiple Subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cname-record, dns-zone, cloudflare

I'm using Cloudflare (no proxy) to manage DNS Records. I have two servers with IP:

- 128.xxx.xxx.xxx
- 174.xxx.xx.x

And these are the DNS Records that I have created:

| Type | Name | Content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | example.com | 128.xxx.xxx.xxx |
| CNAME | sub1 | example.com |
| CNAME | sub2 | example.com |
| CNAME | sub3 | example.com |

**Now, I want to point the main domain (example.com) to the new IP (174.xxx.xx.x), the subdomains (sub1, sub2, sub3) keep using 128.xxx.xxx.xxx.**

I could of course change the DNS records for each subdomain to type A by pointing all subdomains to IP 128.xxx.xxx.xxx like this:

| Type | Name | Content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | example.com | 174.xxx.xx.x |
| A | sub1.example.com | 128.xxx.xxx.xxx |
| A | sub2.example.com | 128.xxx.xxx.xxx |
| A | sub3.example.com | 128.xxx.xxx.xxx |

The problem is, I have a lot of subdomains and the number is growing, I don't want to manually write the IP for the subdomains, apart from many, I'm also worried that I will switch servers with different IP addresses later.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

I really appreciate any answer, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an A record `cname.example.com`, with the `128.xxx.xxx.xxx` IP address.

Then for each domain, you would have CNAME point to `cname.example.com`.